# Not sure what is wrong with my code (Tkinter BEGINNER)

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter, frame

I'm making a pretty simple GUI and each frame should have a Continue and Exit button. I need the continue button to open a new frame with writing, widgets...etc on it.

The first frame (`frame1`) works when I call the `frame_2` function.
But from this I do not know how to open a `frame_3` and destroy `frame 2` properly.

Here is the code so far:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.constants import *
tk = tkinter.Tk()


def frame_2(): #ENTERING AGE
    frame1.grid_forget()
    frame1.destroy()
    frame2 = tkinter.Frame(tk, borderwidth=2,)
    frame2.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1,pady=50,padx=80)

    need_info = tkinter.Label(frame2, text="I need some information first...")
   need_info.grid(row=0, column=0) #displays text at top of frame

    enter_age = tkinter.Label(frame2, text="Please enter your age!")
    enter_age.grid(row=2, column=0) #displays second line of text

    age = tkinter.Entry(frame2, width=10)
    age.grid(row=3, column=0)

    nextpage = tkinter.Button(frame2,text="Continue",command=frame2.destroy)
    nextpage.grid(row=10, column=0)
    exitapp = tkinter.Button(frame2,text="Exit",command=tk.destroy) #exits programme
    exitapp.grid(row=12, column=0)


def frame_three(): #ENTERING EDUCATION
    frame_2().grid.forget()
    frame_2().destroy()
    frame3 = tkinter.Frame(tk, borderwidth=2)
    frame3.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1,pady=50,padx=80)

def frame_3(): #ENTERING EDUCATION
    frame_2().grid.forget()
    frame_2().destroy()
    frame3 = tkinter.Frame(tk, borderwidth=2)
    frame3.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1,pady=50,padx=80)
    age_confirm = tkinter.Label(frame3, text="You entered 38!")
    age_confirm.grid(row=0, column=0)
    nextpage.grid(row=10, column=0)
    exitapp = tkinter.Button(frame2,text="Exit",command=tk.destroy) #exits programme
    exitapp.grid(row=12, column=0)





frame1 = tkinter.Frame(tk, borderwidth=2) #WELCOME PAGE, a.k.a The first frame
frame1.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1,pady=50,padx=80)
label = tkinter.Label(frame1, text="Welcome to NAME GAME! I'm going to guess who you are...")
label.grid(row=0, column=0) #displays text at top of frame


nextpage = tkinter.Button(frame1,text="Continue",command=frame_2)

def frame_2(): #ENTERING AGE
    frame1.grid_forget()
    frame1.destroy()
    frame2 = tkinter.Frame(tk, borderwidth=2,)
    frame2.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1,pady=50,padx=80)

    need_info = tkinter.Label(frame2, text="I need some information first...")
    need_info.grid(row=0, column=0) #displays text at top of frame

    enter_age = tkinter.Label(frame2, text="Please enter your age!")
    enter_age.grid(row=2, column=0) #displays second line of text

    age = tkinter.Entry(frame2, width=10)
    age.grid(row=3, column=0)

    nextpage = tkinter.Button(frame2,text="Continue",command=frame_3)
    nextpage.grid(row=10, column=0)
    exitapp = tkinter.Button(frame2,text="Exit",command=tk.destroy) #exits programme
    exitapp.grid(row=12, column=0)

nextpage.grid(row=2, column=0)
exitapp = tkinter.Button(frame1,text="Exit",command=tk.destroy) #exits programme
exitapp.grid(row=4, column=0)



tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you can't tell us what's wrong, how do you expect us to tell you how to fix it? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Are you aware that you are having defined two functions called "frame_2" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit messed up.
Find below a working example.
Before you post any other question, make sure that your code is "runable", if you are struggling with logical issues or post your error messages (the errors printed in python console).

Please also make sure that your indentation is correct.

As I am using python 2.7 you would need to replace `Tkinter` by `tkinter`.
May be that you need to import `BOTH` from `tkinter.constants` again.

What was wrong in your code?

- You used similar names for objects and functions. What came around doing this was that you tried `frame_2().grid.forget()` - what is wrong about it? You would need to call something on a function call (`frame_2()`) instead of an object (`frame2`). This object was also not declared as global so no chance to get a hold of the object you wanted but declaring it globally. (Including initialization and usage)
  What else is wrong about that line? The function is called `grid_forget` and not `forget` on the grid object that is part of your "function call object"
- Second thing: you used the same function name for two different functions. *Do not do that*. Just don't.

```
import Tkinter 
tk = Tkinter.Tk()
def frame_2(): 
    """
     ENTERING AGE
    """
    global frame1
    global frame2
    if frame1 != None:
            frame1.grid_forget()
            frame1.destroy()
            frame1=None
    frame2 = Tkinter.Frame(tk, borderwidth=2,)
    frame2.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH,expand=1,pady=50,padx=80)
    need_info = Tkinter.Label(frame2, text="I need some information first...")
    need_info.grid(row=0, column=0) #displays text at top of frame
    enter_age = Tkinter.Label(frame2, text="Please enter your age!")
    enter_age.grid(row=2, column=0) #displays second line of text

    age = Tkinter.Entry(frame2, width=10)
    age.grid(row=3, column=0)

    nextpage = Tkinter.Button(frame2,text="Continue",command=frame_3)
    nextpage.grid(row=10, column=0)
    exitapp = Tkinter.Button(frame2,text="Exit",command=tk.destroy) #exits programme
    exitapp.grid(row=12, column=0)

def frame_3(): #ENTERING EDUCATION
    global frame2
    global frame3
    if frame2!=None:
        frame2.grid_forget()
        frame2.destroy()
        frame2=None
    frame3 = Tkinter.Frame(tk, borderwidth=2)
    frame3.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH,expand=1,pady=50,padx=80)
    age_confirm = Tkinter.Label(frame3, text="You entered 38!")
    age_confirm.grid(row=0, column=0)
    exitapp = Tkinter.Button(frame3,text="Exit",command=tk.destroy) #exits programme
    exitapp.grid(row=12, column=0)

frame2=None
frame3=None
frame1 = Tkinter.Frame(tk, borderwidth=2) #WELCOME PAGE, a.k.a The first frame
frame1.pack(fill=Tkinter.BOTH,expand=1,pady=50,padx=80)
label = Tkinter.Label(frame1, text="Welcome to NAME GAME! I'm going to guess who you are...")
label.grid(row=0, column=0) #displays text at top of frame

nextpage = Tkinter.Button(frame1,text="Continue",command=frame_2)
nextpage.grid(row=2, column=0)
exitapp = Tkinter.Button(frame1,text="Exit",command=tk.destroy) #exits programme
exitapp.grid(row=4, column=0)

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, that code runs really smoothly. All that had to be done was change anywhere it says 'Tkinter' to 'tkinter' but now it's all working. Thanks a lot!